# Program an applications print files

Tags: programming

i wanna make an app that get files and print it.how can i do that ? with which program language ? 
this program is like to get file from any protocol and read last line of it and print it automatically.

thanks

Comment: #ubuntu-motu ,#ubuntu-app-devel are the best areas

Answer (score 1):

In very simple terms you can print with the `lp` command. Pass it a file and it'll print it.

```
lp testfile
lp <(echo "this is a test")
```

There are a [ton of options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lp.1posix.html) but there you go.

The file selection and programming language are really up to you. What I've given you can be called from just about any of them and they all have their own ways of working but here's a *super* simple shell script that uses Zenity for a GUI file-picker.

```
#!/bin/sh
lp $(zenity --file-selection)
```

But it's obviously not going to understand every format. You might need to run printing of some formats via the applications that understand the format. Eg Inkscape for SVG... Or raster them to a format your printer can understand.